# Saving date and time into the database using django

Tags: html, django

I have created a date and time for my website where users will choose the date and time but I not sure how to save it into the database that I had.

Below is images of how it looks like on my website and the code for it.
[image]

my reception.html

```
<script>
      $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
      });
    </script>
  <div  class="form-group m-3" >
       <h4> Hello {{ user.username }}, you are at the Reception Unserviceable Page</h4>
       <p>Select a date and Time</p>
    <div class="input-group date" style="width:300px" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input required name="datetime" type="text"  class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"  />
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to create a Model, then a ModelForm, then submit it and save it in the database in a view. This question is too broad to be answered here. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to store this information somewhere, that's where [Django Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/) come in. Most commonly you would use a [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#model-field-types) for that which comes with a default [DateTimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput) to render in your template.

Steps you'll have to take:

1. Create a Model that includes a DateTimeField
2. Create a ModelForm based on that Model
3. Return the ModelForm when rendering the template (so include in the context of your view)
4. Render the form in your template
5. On submit of the form, process the DateTime object and save it to the database

For timezone specific logic please refer to [django.utils.timezone](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now). Django uses the timezone specificed in `TIME_ZONE` setting as default timezone. So if you want to have your timezone, change the default.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE):

> When USE_TZ is False, this is the time zone in which Django will store all datetimes. When USE_TZ is True, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

Comment: I did try the django own date time but the time is not accurate, the time is 8 Hour difference from my region

Comment: is there anyway to match my own region?

Comment: ok, let me take a look

Comment: @Shadowwalker just wanna highlight that this is not part of the question here. Rather raise a new one concerning timezones.